# bypassing mod_security on Dreamhost for post content

Tags: javascript, mod-security

I've written my own simple blog software to display syntax-highlighted code, and it all works perfectly on my localhost, but I'm having trouble on my Dreamhost server.

The first time I've posted code including the word 'function' (or possibly 'function ()'), it got rejected by mod_security.

I'm the only user allowed to post, so I can probably get away with turning mod_security off, but I'm wondering if there's a way to bypass the problem. EncodeURLComponent(content) didn't help.

I guess I could write a function to break up problem words, but I'm hoping there's something already available. Any ideas?

Comment: [sf] would be a better place to ask questions like this.

Comment: I'll give it a go @Barmar, but both look like they cover the same sort of questions. What's the difference between StackOverflow and ServerFault?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, SF is for server operations. Configuring a DreamHost server is server operations.

Comment: Ah, but I don't want to configure a server. I want to find a way to send data without triggering a server security feature. I'm looking for code to 'clean' my post data.

I already know that I can't configure the mod_security on Dreamhost, and I know how to turn it off if I choose to go that route.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing this in the first place. It means every blog about programming needs to disable mod_security, which seems unlikely. My guess is the folks at SF will know how to customize it so you can just disable this specific check without removing the whole mod_security.

Comment: Could you read the server's log? I assume you will find the reason there, and based on the result, you can make an (so called) exclusion to avoid this (so called) false positive match.

Comment: Dreamhost doesn't allow modifications to mod_security at this time. https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215947927-Enabling-the-Web-Application-Firewall It's either on or off. I guess I'll just write my own function, but I'll also try asking on Server Fault in case there's something I've missed. Thanks.